# List all users within a OU in Active Directory

Tags: ms-access, vba, adsi

I am trying to list all users with an Organizational Unit using ADSI script on VBA(Access). So far I have only be able to view a single user attribute at time (Name,tile,company,ect) Any idea how I would be able to list all user in a OU, I'm currently bound to the OU but can list or display user within. Please and thank you.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Set objOU = GetObject("LDAP://DC1.widget.internal/OU=Standard Users,OU=Active Users,OU=All Users,DC=widget,DC=internal")
(&
(objectCategory=user)
(objectClass=user)
(userPrincipalName=*))
 Debug.Print objOU.Get("Name")

End Sub
```